# Detecting whether if the matrix mirrors object in OpenGL

Tags: javascript, matrix, 3d, webgl

When a object is mirrored (the product of scale vector's each axis < 0), the culling mode needs to be inverted to prevent visual artifact. (Only back side is visible)

The cube looks normal if scaleX > 0:
[image: Culling is normal if scaleX is 1]

But it looks weird if scaleX < 0:
[image: Culling breaks if scaleX is -1]

We can invert culling mode to solve this problem.

```
gl.cullFace(gl.FRONT)
```

However, I'd like to test a matrix whether if the culling should be inverted or not. But, because of the rotation, I'm not sure how I can do this.

Is there a way to detect whether if the matrix mirrors an object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just check if the [determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant) of your transfromation matrix is negative. This can also be interpreted as a change in ["handedness"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orientation_%28vector_space%29) of your coordinate space.